# How to remove title in extends Dialog implements Context

Tags: android, android-layout

As I Mentioned i just want to remove title in my code

```
package com.example.dialogbox2;
    import android.app.Dialog;  
    import android.content.Context;  
    import android.os.Bundle;  
    import android.view.View;  
    import android.widget.Button;  
    public class Custom extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{  
        public Custom(Context context) {  
            super(context);  
    }  
    Button btn;  
        @Override  
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            setContentView(R.layout.custom);  
            setTitle("This Is Sample Title");
            btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.dismis_dialog);  
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);  
        }  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            dismiss();  
        }  
    }
```

When i remvoe `setTitle("This Is Sample Title");` on code its still showing a litle space with a Black Background

Here this is my Layout

```
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
   android:background="#ef8e01"  
   android:orientation="vertical" >  
    <TextView  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_margin="10dp"  
     android:text="@string/msg"  
     android:textColor="#000"
     android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >  
   </TextView>  
   <Button  
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  
     android:clickable="true" android:id="@+id/dismis_dialog"  
     android:text="@string/dismis" />  
  </LinearLayout>
```

Please help me to fix this 
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to remove your title bar :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```